# Getting character string buffer too small error in PL/SQL script?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am a newbie in PL/SQL.

I am writing a small script that will help me join a collection to a database table. Th collection will contain thousands of IDs, but here, for the sake of simplicity, i have kept it very small.

```
VARIABLE cursor REFCURSOR;
DECLARE
  your_collection SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
BEGIN
  your_collection.EXTEND(2);
  FOR i IN 1 .. 2 LOOP
    your_collection(i) := DBMS_RANDOM.STRING( '7839', '7689' );
  END LOOP;
  OPEN :cursor FOR
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   emp t
         INNER JOIN
         TABLE( your_collection ) c
         ON t.empno = c.COLUMN_VALUE;
END;
/
PRINT cursor;
```

Here is the error im getting.

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_RANDOM", line 144
ORA-06512: at line 6
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

CURSOR
```

Help me correct my script if there are other errors as well. I will be really grateful.

Comment: Presumably the problem is happening in this comparison:  `t.empno = c.COLUMN_VALUE`.  As the message suggests, check the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DBMS_RANDOM.STRING()`](https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14258_02/d_random.htm#i996825) takes two arguments:

- the first is a single character which specifies the type of characters which are randomly generated; and
- the second is the length.

The error is being produced as you are supplying a 4-character length value to the first argument when it will only accept a 1-character length value.

What you are probably intending to do is:

```
VARIABLE cursor REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  your_collection SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
BEGIN
  your_collection.EXTEND(2); -- Set the length of the array
  your_collection(1) := '7839'; -- Specify the first value in the array.
  your_collection(2) := '7689'; -- Specify the second value in the array.

  OPEN :cursor FOR
  SELECT t.*
  FROM   emp t
         INNER JOIN
         TABLE( your_collection ) c
         ON t.empno = c.COLUMN_VALUE;
END;
/

PRINT cursor;
```

or more simply (and converted to numbers since the values appear to be numeric):

```
...

DECLARE
  your_collection SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST := SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 7839, 7689 );
BEGIN    
  OPEN :cursor FOR

  ...
```